# jQuery and Bootstrap included by theme but cannot be used

Tags: jquery, drupal-7, drupal-themes

I have a Drupal site with a purchased theme - [see it here](http://umes.mb.ca).

The theme includes jQuery 2.x and Bootstrap in the `<head>` section of the page, but trying to access the `$`variable gives `Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drupal stores jQuery in a variable called `jQuery` (using jQuery's `noConflict` mode - see `drupal.js`) rather than `$` to avoid conflicts with other libraries like Prototype.

```
// Allow other JavaScript libraries to use $.
jQuery.noConflict();
```

You can just do:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    // normal jQuery stuff here
    $.whatever
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the example! I was worried I'd have to change every line :D